# nuts-n-bolts of WCF?

Tags: wcf

Is there any Absolute Beginner's tutorial available on Web for WCF that comprehensively describes the underlying technologies, protocols and other relevant stuff.

Just cramming the ABCs and other conventions make me feel bad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I bought [Essential Windows Communication Foundation](http://www.amazon.co.uk/reader/0321440064?_encoding=UTF8&ref_=sib_dp_pt#reader-link). It's not a bad book and good for learning the fundamentals. I have found some occasions though where I wanted to know something specific and the book just didn't have enough detail. But for picking up WCF, I recommend it.

Answer (score 0):

I found unleashed to be a good book to get the nuts and bolts: [http://www.amazon.com/Windows-Communication-Foundation-Unleashed-WCF/dp/0672329484](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0672329484)

Has a lot of examples and covers pretty much all of the various wcf facets